# Which of the following is not a proper ideal group

Tags: abstract-algebra

Which of the following is NOT a proper ideal group of $ \mathbb{Z}_{12} $ ?

a)<5>

b)<8>

c)<2>

d)<3>

e)<4>

f)none

Currently reviewing abstract algebra and I am not sure how to go about this question. Can someone explain what an ideal group is in detail?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what an ideal group is, but I know what an ideal is.  $(a)=
\mathbb{Z}_n$ if and only if gcd$(a,n)=1$.  This is because of the Bezout property of the integers.  In this case, there are integers $s,t \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $as+nt=1$ so $as \equiv 1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ and is a unit.  Any ideal containing a unit in a ring will necessarily be the entire ring since if $\lambda \in U(R)$, then $r=(r\lambda^{-1})\lambda$.  So if you pick one of those which is relatively prime to $12$, it will generate the whole ring and not be a proper ideal.